# Winter Bash 2018 hat progres

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Is there a way to check the progress on a specific hat? For example, for the "Gonna Find Out" how many more votes are needed to reach 150?

Comment: I think the requirement for secret hats should be kept secret:)

Comment: no way, they will simply pop by magic on your profile ... you can only hope that happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's simply impossible to see hat progress. It has never been shown, and you can't see it.

It the challenge of Winter Bash, so you're unable to know, so you should just vote as usual and see your luck.

<del>You could try to compose a query on [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), or ask a question on Stack Overflow for asking how to do your expected query.
So you can post a new one on [this link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).</del>

*What I mentioned above is false. It's impossible to do that, since votes are anonymous.*

---

So after all, you have to try your luck for that hat :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to check the progress on a **specific** hat? For example, for the "Gonna Find Out" ...

It depends on which hat, as you are aware "Gonna Find Out" is obtained after you "cast 150 votes on questions or answers".

You have 9 votes system wide.

Some are easier to track than others, and some are obtained by [means not yet understood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list).

So get a piece of paper, or restrict your votes to one site, and make **fair and properly considered** votes - we wouldn't want people to vote randomly simply to obtain a hat, and there are easier hats to obtain.

For example: The "Pizza Hat" looks delicious, it is earned after you "post a competing answer to an existing accepted answer, reaching a score of at least +3".

PS: You don't have to wear it on your head, you can shrink it and put it in your mouth. I earned that hat already, and I really only need one of each.